# How to replace specific values in an ffdf?

Tags: r, ff

I want to replace all values within an ffdf (using ff package in R for large data). Typically, in a normal dataframe, I would use something like this:

```
df[df>0] <- 1
```

Is there an analogous method for ffdf? I wish to keep the object as class "ffdf".

Comment: It looks like `df[which(df[, 1:ncol(df)] > 0, arr.ind = TRUE)] <- 1` works, but I have no experience with this and perhaps it's not the nicest way. Also perhaps it's not very efficient as `df[, 1:ncol(df)]` seems to be converting `df` to a `data.frame`.

Comment: Yes, so far this has been my problem. I cannot execute the command without converting to a dataframe. I should add this to the original question.